# How to create new webpages automatically based on user input?

Tags: php

This question may have been asked before but I couldn;t really find it.
What I want to do is, websites like pastebin.com, even stackoverflow, these generate new webpages based on user input showing that data from what I can understand.

I want to make it like that. User enters something, and he is given a permalink to share that information.

How to do this using PHP ?

EDIT: Here is an example

Like, I want it that
instead of having something like www.example.com/view.php?id=123

I want it like

www.example.com/view/123

Comment: this is impossible with php, you will need to do this with .htaccess's mod rewrite.

Comment: You should learn very basic things before you understand this, including autoloading, and routing. What you're looking here is covered in details in any framework's blog tutorial.

Comment: If you use Codeigniter framework which is php mvc you will easily able to send data in multiple segment like you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible to be done with PHP, you can do this with .htaccess's url rewriting.

a good article about this can be found at: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: I know how it works. Thing is, let us say I have the website www.example.com and the user puts some stuff in text and heading and something. I want it to appear on a link such as www.example.com/asdas.php .. something which anyone can access later on, and without using the php '?' parameters of GET/POST

Comment: that has nothing to do with PHP and is rather done with .htaccess's URL rewrite engine.

Comment: aha.. can you link me to an answer regarding this? i really dont know what to search for

Answer (score 0):

In this site , work some ajax function, when you add some data in textarea and click submit, called function , that saved current data in db, and return some json data , and then show you in some format.

Comment: how do i get a permalink/

Comment: sorry ? In pastebin.com work some post.php , you can write some function, and afeter save redirect to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply done like this:

Create a index.php containing a input field where the user inputs their data.
Post data to the server and create a random string which will be the users permalink.
Then insert the random string and data into a database.

In the index.php file say that if any uri is added after your domain like example.com/
it checks against the database if this code exists in db, and returns the result to the visitor.